# sequence of tenses in subordinate sentences

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

> The UK could flourish once the shackles of EU membership were released.

or

> The UK could flourish once the shackles of EU membership had been released.

Comment: *Could* implies that the flourishing has yet to take place, so the release can't be in the past: "once the shackles ... **are** released."

Comment: "have been released" is also possible.